# adding a default thumbnail to a wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently the code in a wordpress plugin looks like this:

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <div class = 'reddit-image pull-left' style = 'width:180px'>                                      

            <img src = "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" width = "180px" class="img-rounded"> 
            </div>
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <div class = 'reddit-image pull-left' style = 'width:180px'>


<img src = "<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpedditimage', true ); ?>" width = "180px" class="img-rounded"> 
</div>
```

Originally the plugin required the user to attach an image URL to a text post via front end submission form.  I made it so that you can post text without the image.   The posts show up as a list in a page.  Each post that is listed has thumbnail on the left, and text on the right.  It was great that I disabled the image attachment requirement, but when I make text-only posts theres a blank space on the left side of text. I'm trying to fill up this blank space with a default thumbnail image.  I don't know if this involves a if/elseif/else or something.

Comment: It looks like your code is already doing that. It checks if it has a post thumbnail set, and if so, displays that. If not it displays `<img src = "<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpedditimage', true ); ?>" width = "180px" class="img-rounded"> `. The closing bracelet for the else{ is missing tough. You can change the `src=` from the else statement to the default thumbnail

Comment: `<img src = "<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpedditimage', true ); ?>" width = "180px" class="img-rounded">`  this part appears to grab the image from an external URL and sets it as the thumbnail of a post so I probably shouldn't tweak this part.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Wordpress Plugin that does that:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/default-post-thumbnail-image/

You can also write the following code:

```
<?php 
if(has_post_thumbnail()){
    the_post_thumbnail();
} else {
    ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/default-image.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

As mentioned in the following post: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-set-a-default-fallback-image-for-wordpress-post-thumbnails/

The only thing wrong in your code is the image source ("src").